# Kibana: Accessing booleans in Stored Script

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-template

I'm using [Kibana Stored Scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/create-stored-script-api.html) and [Search Templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html) to fetch data.

I have a request to power the Stored Script using a boolean sent through the Search Template.

##### Requirement

My ask is:

- Use a parameter `includeABC` to fetch all docs which have ABC.
- Default value of `includeABC` would be false

##### Current Code

The query part of my stored script is defined as follows:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "{{includeABC}}{{^includeABC}}FALSE{{/includeABC}} && name:ABC"
        }
      },
      {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "NOT {{includeABC}}{{^includeABC}}FALSE{{/includeABC}} && name:*"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

##### Review

When `includeABC` is `true`, I should only get documents which have `name` set as `ABC`. But, that's not the case. I get all documents no matter whats the value of `includeABC`.

Comment: what do you mean by 'doesn't seem to work'? Did you try? if so what you got can you share?

Comment: When `includeABC ` is `true`, I should only get documents which have `name` set as `ABC`. But, that's not the case. I get all documents no matter whats the value of `includeABC `.